# What is my mistake in calculating $**(x\wedge y)$?

Tags: exterior-algebra

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Formal_definition_for_k-vectors), we have that the Hodge star is defined so that 
$$\alpha\wedge *\beta=\langle A,B\rangle\omega,$$
so it seems that in 4-dimensional space with basis $x,y,z,w$ and $\omega=x\wedge y\wedge z\wedge w$, we should have 
$$*(x\wedge y)=z\wedge w$$
and also 
$$*(z\wedge w)=x\wedge y$$
because $\langle x\wedge y, x\wedge y\rangle=1$ and $\langle w\wedge z, w\wedge z\rangle=1.$

However, again according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Duality), we have
$$**(\eta)=-1^{k(n-k)}s\eta,$$
where $s=1$ if $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product.  So, we should have
$$**(x\wedge y)=-x\wedge y.$$

Which step am I making a mistake in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the formula $**(\eta)=(-1)^{k(n-k)}s\eta,$ $n$ is the dimension of the vector space and $k$ is the degree of $\eta$.  So in your case with $\eta=x\wedge y$, $n=4$ and $k=2$ so $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$ is $1$, not $-1$.